# Formating latex table

Tags: tables, formatting

I would like to create a table that looks like the following figure
[image: Desired table] using the following latex code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|cccccc|ccc|}
        \cmidrule{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{SOME OTHER HEADER}        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{HEADER} \\
        \cmidrule{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & F     & G     & H     & I \\
        \cmidrule{2-11}    \multirow{6}[2]{*}{\begin{sideways}OTHER HEADER\end{sideways}} & A     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & B     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & C     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & D     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & E     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & F     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        \cmidrule{2-11}    \end{tabular}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the above code gives me this ugly table instead
[image]
How can I improve my code to reflect my desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with [tabu](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf), the tabularx extension.

[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\sffamily
\scriptsize
\caption{The caption}
\def\Thickness{2pt} % Set the thickness for the verticl and horizontal rules.
\arrayrulewidth=\Thickness % Thickness for \cline
\tabulinesep = _3pt^5pt % Celll text separation _{texbox-bottomRule}^{textbox-topRule}
\tabulinestyle{\Thickness black} % Thickness and color for \tabucline
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth  {X[0.1]|X[0.5r]|*6{X[c]}|*3{X[c]}|}
\cline{3-11}
%Row2
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
& \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries SOME OTHER HEADER}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries HEADER} \\ \cline{3-11}
%Row3
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & F     & G     & H     & I \\ \cline{2-11}
& A     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
& B     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
& C     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
& D     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
& E     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries OTHER HEADER}}& F     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\[-\Thickness] \tabucline{2-11}
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best solution as it perfectly mirror my intended outcome

Comment: I always try to obtain the result that is closest to the desired one, as long as there are packages that allow it to do so. tabu allows making tables as beautiful and customizable as those of MSword ...

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you only want to get rid of the gaps, you only need to replace your `\cmidrules` by `\clines`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|cccccc|ccc|}
        \cline{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{SOME OTHER HEADER}        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{HEADER} \\
        \cline{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & F     & G     & H     & I \\
        \cline{2-11}    \multirow{6}[2]{*}{\begin{sideways}OTHER HEADER\end{sideways}} & A     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & B     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & C     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & D     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & E     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & F     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        \cline{2-11}    \end{tabular}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want different line widths, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple tabular solution with increased horizontal and vertical spaces by renewing `\arraystretch` and using `m` columntypes instead of `c`.

Also, replaced `\cmidrule`s with `\cline`s as marmot did

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.7cm}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.9cm}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|CCCCCC|DDD|}
        \cline{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{SOME OTHER HEADER}        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{HEADER} \\
        \cline{3-11}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & F     & G     & H     & I \\
        \cline{2-11}    \multirow{6}[2]{*}{\begin{sideways}OTHER HEADER\end{sideways}} & A     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & B     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & C     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & D     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & E     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        & F     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
        \cline{2-11}    \end{tabular}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution. This is the easiest answer to adapt to my initial code as I do not need to make lots of changes